# node.js exception object is empty in try/catch block

Tags: node.js, exception

In the following function:

```
function processDeviceOffline(deviceID) {
  var sqlstr = sql.format("SELECT Location, Name FROM devices WHERE DeviceID = ?", [deviceID]);
  var query = db.query(sqlstr, function(err, result){
    try {
        if (err) {
          console.log("processDeviceOffline SQL error: %j", err);
          console.log('When '+deviceID+' reported Offline');
        } else {
          if (result[0]) {
            utils.notify('Device Offline: '+result[0].Name+'-'+result[0].Location+')');
          } else {
            utils.notify(`Unknown Device Offline: ${deviceID}`);
          }
        }
    } catch(ex) {
      console.log("processDeviceOffline %j (%j)", ex, result);
    }
  });
}
```

I get the following log message:

```
processDeviceOffline {} (undefined)
```

Why is the exception object 'ex' empty?

Comment: What is `utils.notify`? Is it supposed to throw? Is it asynchronous?

Comment: It's just a function that ends up doing a console.log at the moment. My problem is that node executes the final console.log in the above snippet with the first parameter empty implying that the exception is empty. What therefore caused the exception?

Comment: The utils.notify only contains:   console.log("Notify: %s %j", moment().format("dd HH:mm"), msg);

Comment: Have the same issue? did you solve it?  'use strict' maybe?

Comment: The problem was that my catch was inside a promise.... I ended up doing something like..

`catch (err){
                        console.error(err);
                        let msg = \`${err}\`;
                        reject(msg);
                }`